# html5 data attributes containing a boolean value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html, asp.net-mvc-4

In our DEVELOPMENT environment, we were using the HTML5 data attributes to hold boolean values (I now know this is not the way to go).  So for example:

```
<div id="x" data-mydata="True"></div>
```

And then in our JS code (using jQuery) we were successfully picking up the boolean value:

```
var v = $('#x').data().mydata;
if(v == 'True') {...}
```

And this worked perfectly - and equally so for False values.

However, when we pushed this to our QA environment it stopped working.  Although we set the value to "True", the value as read by the jQuery selector was "data-mydata" (the name of the data attribute).

As mentioned above, we've learnt the correct way to handle boolean values (if the value is false, then exclude the data attribute).

But, my question is: Why was this working one way (incorrectly) in our Dev environment?  We're using the same version of jQuery and as far as I've checked, the dlls are the same version.

FYI - our development environment is currently: VS2010, ASP.NET MVC4 .NET 4.0.

Thanks

Griff

Comment: Were you using the same browser in dev and test ?

Comment: Have you guys tried var v = $('#x').data('mydata')?

Comment: Same browser in all tests and also tried all different variations in the JS script for accessing the value of the data attribute

Comment: Just to clarify - same browser run from the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seem `.data` being used like that before but if it works on your local machine I will assume the browser is not the same in the QA environment and having issues getting the value:

Try changing the code to either:

```
 var v = $('#x').data("mydata");

 var v = $("#x").attr("data-mydata");
```

Comment: We test using IE8/9, Firefox and Chrome - same results in all.  I think the .attr() method will work, but wanted consistency here by using the .data() method.  

Tried using both .data('name') and .data().name syntaxes with the same result.

Comment: @DrGriff I have had trouble with .data() too in older browsers.  I had to use the .attr approach when this occurs.

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of these browsers.

Comment: Sadly, I never got to the bottom of this.  We corrected our pattern and moved on.